# Viewbag does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have checked all the possible solution for this on stack overflow like to clear cache file, to change version number in `web.config` file of `Shared` View Folder but still not able to solve this kind of issue in partial view

```
var count = parseInt('@Viewbag.FeedbackCount');
```

Can someone suggest better and clean solution for this rather than to mark it as duplicate?

Comment: Viewbag is only in Razor AFAIK. Are you calling that in .cs or in .cshtml?

Comment: i am calling it in .cshtml

Comment: What is the result of `@Viewbag.FeedbackCount` ? And what is the error message in the browsers console? (F12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `ViewBag` with a capital **B** instead of `Viewbag`.

Comment: Damn..i can't Believe i have wasted 2 hrs in this :(

Comment: @Steve I bet you won't make the same mistake twice though ;-)

Comment: Definitely not mate

Answer (score 0):

Is that JavaScript Code

if it is JavaScript you could do something like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="MyValue" value="@Viewbag.FeedbackCount">
```

then

```
var count = parseInt($('#MyValue').val());
```

I had a similar need (But there must be a better way)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use.

```
// these 2 lines
int count;
Int32.TryParse(ViewBag.FeedbackCount, out count))
// or just use one statemnt
int count= Int32.Parse(ViewBag.FeedbackCount);
```

if the above doesn't work try to use ViewData to send your data

```
int count = Int32.Parse(ViewData["FeedbackCount"]);
```

i think one of them should do the trick.

Comment: why down vote ? what is wrong ? i used it for some projects.

Comment: Not my downvote, but OP is using javascript (inside the razor view), you are using C#